# Css3 background-image animation animate too soon

Tags: css, animation, background-image, css-animations

I am trying to do a css3 animation on **multiple elements**.
All those elements have **different background-image** and they must be replace in the middle of the animation.
The thing is, I want to use the **same animation for all elements**.
Wich mean, I can't write the original background-image in the animation.
But, the absence of original background-image make the background-image animate with the rest.
I think I would need something like:

```
background-image: default;
```

But I don't think it exist.
Anyone have an idea?

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/4SRrR/
*(Look how the background-image start fading to the red one before the div is out of the screen.)*

**Html:**

```
<div class="anim"></div>
```

**Css:**

```
.anim {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/15485/Step1.png");
    -webkit-animation: anim .75s forwards ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);}
    51% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px); background-image: url("http://www.vt2k.com/processing/images/redball.jpg");}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px); background-image: url("http://www.vt2k.com/processing/images/redball.jpg");}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One posibility would be to have 2 backgrounds, and then in the animation just reference the sizes of the first and the second one:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/4SRrR/1/)

The CSS would be:

```
.anim {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/15485/Step1.png"), url("http://www.vt2k.com/processing/images/redball.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: anim 7.5s forwards ease-in;

}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px); background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 0%;}
    50% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 0%;}
    51% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px); background-size: 0% 0%, 100% 100%; }
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);  background-size: 0% 0%, 100% 100%;}
}
```

I have increased the duraion of the transition so that it is more visible. And also overdefined the background-size; it wouldn't be necesary to repeat it in every frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to what the question is but I'll take a stab at it.  If you take the 51% animation off then it seems to work slightly better.  It will shrink until it is gone and then as it comes back the background-image fades in.

One of the hard things with CSS3 animations is that there isn't an easy way to tell when the animation is 50% done.  What you could do is 2 keyframe animations.  With JS you can listen for the first animation ending.  You could add the background-image and then the class that will trigger the second part of the animation.  It's not pretty but could work.